# Value of a transcendental function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to transform really just evaluate or simplify:

Log($\sinh(1+i))$

into

Log($\sinh^2(1) + \sin^2(1)) + i\theta$ where $\theta=\arctan(\frac{\tan(1)}{\tanh(1)})$

I have tried the following:
transforming sinh(1+i) into $\frac{1}{2}(e^{1+i}+e^{-(1+i)})$
Finding an identity

I keep getting stuck

I have gotten up to:
$Log(\sinh(1)\cos(1)+i\cosh(1)\sin(1)$ I was hoping to be able to simplify it so I could use the complex formula for Log any help would be lovely.

Note I am using Log instead of log because we are working with the principal value

Comment: Note that $$\sinh (1+i) = \sinh 1\cos 1 + i \cosh 1 \sin 1 = \sqrt{\sinh^2 1 + \sin^2 1} \exp\left(i \arctan (\coth 1\tan 1)\right).$$